# Ubuntu Log creation permission issues after Fabric build

Tags: django, ubuntu, logging, permissions

My Django app is built on a VM Ubuntu instance via a Fabric script ran from my local dev machine as root with sudo. The Fabric script sets up a folder in:

```
/var/log/FOLDERNAME
```

and the app is set to log all log data into it.

However after each build even though the right permissions (group & folder) exist on the folder (ls -all confirms it) the log files have trouble getting generated unless I SSH to the box after each Fabric build and physically type in:

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/log/FOLDERNAME -Rf
```

... then everything works fine.

Can anyone please shed some light and/or point me in the right direction to solve this?
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

use [put](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.put) with `mode` to setup your logfile folder with permissions.

```
put('yourlogfile', 'yourlogfile', mode=0755)
```

A sidenote: Using `chmod 777` is generally not a good idea. If your VM is running ubuntu your apache runs by default as `www-data`. chown www-data and r-w permissions for this user/group should be enough.

Comment: Hey thanks for responding. However I am not putting any files on the remote drive. Only creating a folder with certain permissions.